# Max Rows Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to generate a table and insert it into a Word document, as follows:

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
var paragraph = miDoc.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table tablaEvaluacion = 
Globals.ThisDocument.Tables.Add(paragraph.Range, lstContacto.Count + 1, lstEvaluacion.Count + 3, ref missing, ref missing);
```

But when the number of rows exceeds 63 this causes an exception: "`COMException was unhandled by user code. The number must be between 1 and 63.`"

Answer (score 6):

First of all - *are you 100% sure you mean rows?* As you can read from my answer in the following, I have no problems inserting more than 63 rows in a table, but inserting more than 63 columns however, causes the same problems as you describe.

Anyway, I have tried investigating this - here is what I've found:

Using Google:

- A similar question has been asked here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officegeneral/thread/662b1bf2-6067-46e5-8def-c23d86cf0549/ - It seems that it has just been concluded that this is a limitation set by Word - but AFAIK with no hard evidence (read: references to any documentation).

Using the documentation:

- The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.tables.add%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is not of much help here as the limit is not mentioned.

Using dotPeek:

- I tried decompiling the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Tables` type, in the hope of finding a comment describing the limit - but with no luck. The code simply invoces the function in Word using `COM` so it is very likely that the Exception bubbles all the way from Word, through the interop assembly and into your code.

Using my own sample implementation:

```
documentA.Tables.Add(range, 01, 64); // COMException -> "The number must be between 1 and 63."
documentA.Tables.Add(range, 01, 63); // All good
documentA.Tables.Add(range, 64, 01); // All good
```

The sample code shows that when I try using more than 63 columns, the `COMException` you refer to is thrown. I'm running MS Office 2013 with version 15 of the Interop API btw.

Using MS Word 2013:

- By first using my sample application to insert a table with 63 columns, I then opened the document and asked Word to insert yet another column - this gave me the following error:

[image]

So what this boils down to is that 63 columns seem to be the max number of columns you are allowed to insert.

Hope this helped settle things ;)